# Use PIVOT in BIGQUERY with a multi-column ARRAY STRUCT

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BIGQUERY with three columns, I'm pivoting the first column but I need an ARRAY to be formed with the other two columns:

This is my table:

| fecData | total | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202301 | 250 | first |
| 202302 | 50 | sec |
| 202303 | 100 | th |

This is the query with the values:

```
WITH initTable AS (
  SELECT '202301' AS fecData, 250 AS total, 'first' as name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '202302' AS fecData, 50 AS total, 'sec' as name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '202303' AS fecData, 100 AS total, 'th' as name
),
pivotTable AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM initTable
  PIVOT (
    MAX(total)
    FOR fecData IN ('202301', '202302', '202303')
  )
)
SELECT *
FROM pivotTable
```

This is what I get:

| name | 202301 | 202302 | 202303 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | 250 | null | null |
| sec | null | 50 | null |
| th | null | null | 100 |

This is what I need:

| 202301.total | 202301.name | 202302.total | 202302.name | 202303.total | 202303.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | first | 50 | sec | 100 | th |

I need to convert the fecData values into RECORD REPEATED columns that contain the total and name columns with their respective values. I can't apply an ARRAY(STRUCT on the pivoted columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include multiple aggregation functions in the [PIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator).  So, you can try below

```sql
WITH initTable AS (
 -- put sample data here
),
pivotTable AS (
  SELECT * FROM initTable
   PIVOT (
     MAX(total) total, ANY_VALUE(name) name
     FOR fecData IN ('202301', '202302', '202303')
   )
)
SELECT * FROM pivotTable
```

**Query results**

| total_202301 | name_202301 | total_202302 | name_202302 | total_202303 | name_202303 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | first | 50 | sec | 100 | th |

---

or you can consider below as well.

```sql
pivotTable AS (
  SELECT * FROM initTable
   PIVOT (
     ANY_VALUE(STRUCT(total, name))
     FOR fecData IN ('202301', '202302', '202303')
   )
)
```

**Query results**

[image]